Disable code signing for package electron app using electron forge
I am trying to disable the code signing functionality when packaging my electron app using electron forge so I can test my app's functionality on .pkg file distributable. The point is to not get a valid macOS Developer ID Application certificate because I am testing locally.
Here is how to configure electron forge to do code signing in the forge.config.js file:
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    osxSign: {
      identity: "Your Developer ID"
    }
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-pkg',
      config: {
        background: './assets/dmg-background.png',
        format: 'ULFO',
        scripts: './scripts', // Path to the directory containing the postinstall script
        identity: "Your Developer ID", 
        }
    },

I want to convert the above into something like the below:
packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
    osxSign: false,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-pkg',
      config: {
        background: './assets/dmg-background.png',
        format: 'ULFO',
        scripts: './scripts', // Path to the directory containing the postinstall script
        identity: null, 
        }
    },

